# Iptables port forwarding on OpenVZ CEntOS container

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding, centos5, openvz

I am trying to setup a simple port forwarding on an OpenVZ container that is running CentOS 5.5. When I run a command I get errors.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables v1.3.5: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

The same command works fine on hardware node or any other physical server. I know that I can setup port forwarding for that particular container on hardware node, but thats not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your OpenVZ host node does not have netfilter support enabled for the VM guests. If you are the admin of the OpenVZ host, then I refer you to the section entitled "Setting up a firewall that allows per-container configuration" [on this page of OpenVZ wiki](http://wiki.openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall?#Setting_up_a_firewall_that_allows_per-container_configuration).

Comment: After reading the wiki (again). I decided to add `iptable_nat` into list of strings in IPTABLES parameter mentioned in the wiki. And it worked. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
modprobe ip_tables
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe iptable_filter
modprobe ipt_state
```

Try any of these..

i would guess iptable_filter..

And run the command again..

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Did it work?

Comment: No this did not work. Thansk for the answer anyways.